# View flashing when Keyboard appears on React Native Expo Managed Project and Android

Tags: android, react-native, expo, react-navigation-v5

I am practicing in React Native and Expo a very basic project. The project does not use ejected projects so I cannot directly interact with the projects of the specific platforms (Android & iOS) and I want it to remain that way.

A few days ago I saw a problem in Android when trying to edit a field of a login form. It turns out that a small white flash appears before the keyboard opens. As I have read in almost all the Expo pages on GitHub, it is because the application has a blank view of the application and that this behavior could be changed in the projects of these platforms (which I mentioned earlier that I do not have) and I was looking this week to find a way to achieve this then I found this docs but I still don't know if this will work and if it is possible to change said root view color: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/register-root-component/

The video with the keyboard problem: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uOvZl.jpg

The error I am having is the same as in this video but I don't know if there is a way that will solve the problem since I have to use `React Navigation v5` to create a stack for the navigation. Also, I'm using black as background what makes this behavior more noticeable.

I have tried different things such as changing the layout mode of the keyboard (but it makes me lose the ability to scroll), also making it more responsive the view with `KeyboardAvoidingView` and `ScrollView` but it has not been possible.

Here is what I am using:

- Expo SDK 39
- Expo CLI: 3.28.5
- React Navigation v5

Here is some code:

`package.json dependencies`

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "0.1.10",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.10.6",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.8.6",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.12.3",
    "expo": "~39.0.2",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.0.2",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-39.0.4.tar.gz",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.7.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~1.13.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "3.1.4",
    "react-native-screens": "~2.10.1",
    "react-native-web": "~0.13.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "~7.9.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

`App.json`

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "appName",
    "slug": "appName",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "backgroundColor": "#000000",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#000000"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": ["**/*"],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": false
    },
    "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF"
      }
    },
    "androidStatusBar": {
      "barStyle": "light-content",
      "backgroundColor": "#000000"
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    }
  }
}
```

`App.js`

```
import React from "react";
import { View, TextInput } from "react-native";

export default App = () => {
  return (
    <View
      style={{
        backgroundColor: "#000",
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: "center",
        justifyContent: "center",
      }}
    >
      <TextInput
        placeholder="Email"
        placeholderTextColor="#424242"
        style={{
          color: "white",
          backgroundColor: "#d8d8d8",
          padding: 15,

          width: "80%",
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
};
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem. It looks terrible!  I think it has to do with React Navigation.   :\